# Aquery some images are BLANk

Tags: android, image-loading, android-sliding, android-query, aquery

I am using Aquery for a slider menu. Some images in the slider become Blank images. It occurs randomly. The images are selected from server and there is not any problem for any of the images as same images are sometimes showing and sometimes is blanked. can anyone help me to get out from this mess? Another question, is there anyway to find the image returned in aquery is NULL or NOT??

```
aq.id(holder.slide1).image(imgPath, true, true, 0,0, preset, AQuery.FADE_IN);
```

Note: I have already tried changing memCache,filecache, applied preset, etc.

SORRY ONE IMPORTANT POINT THE ERROR SHOWS IN LOLLIPOP NOT IN LOWER VERSIONS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  I have used viewflipper to achieve above slider. Now i have changed it into viewpager. So now the slider is working perfect in all platforms.
 I just used "`cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager`" as viewpager with auto scroll option. thanks to all.